# What is the use of grep -e "Pattern" --regexp=Pattern?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

I know when we are using a

```
grep -e "hello" -e "helo"
```

this will match both `hello` and `helo`, but I saw the following in the man page:

```
-e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
```

What is the meaning of `regexp`?

Comment: Man page says, you can use either `-e PATTERN` or `--regexp=PATTERN`. Both are same thing. `grep -e "hello"` is same as `grep --regexp="hello"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that you can use either `-e` or `--regexp` with the same parameters to get the same behaviour.

So the following are equivalent:

```
grep -e "hello" -e "helo"
grep --regexp='helo' --regexp='hello'
```

---

Note you can get the same behaviour with the regular `grep` by escaping `|`:

```
grep "hello\|helo"
```

or directly using `-E` (or `--extended-regexp`):

```
grep -E "hello|helo"
```

Answer (score 1):

Regexp (or regex) is short for Regular Expression and means that you can grep for a specific pattern, not just a regular string.
E.g. if you want to grep for all lines containing a digit you can do:

```
grep -e "[0-9]" <file>
```

Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression